# Check for Mattanos Levyonim

Tags: purim, halacha, tzedakah-charity

Can you use a check or credit Card for Mattanos Levyonim?

Answer (score 1):

If the poor person can convert the check into cash or food on Purim, then I fulfill the mitzvah (Shvus Yitzchok pg. 99, quoting Rav Elyashiv)
[Source](http://www.closetotorah.com/2011/03/matanos-levyonim-a-halachic-review-q-a/)

Comment: what about Credit?